# Can I merge two git submodules

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I'm working on a repo with submodules.
I have a branch **feature1** that was branched off of **master** branch.
On my **feature1** branch, I made changes to some files in the submodule.
Now the submodule on my **feature1** branch and the submodule on my **master** branch are pointing to two different hashes:
`feature_submodule -> 6c084...`
`master_submodule -> 7b325...`

Some changes were pushed into **master** from another branch by another dev. So to keep my **feature1** branch in sync with **master**, I merged **master** into my **feature1** branch. But now, my **feature_submodule** is no longer pointing to **6c084** but it's pointing to **7b3325**, and the changes I made to the submodule files are gone.

Is there a way to have the submodules merged so that when I'll push my changes into **master** branch, I have the changes I made to my submodule locally while keeping the changes that are on the **master** branch?

Running `git pull --recurse-submodules` only overwrite my local submodules changes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this text explaining how Git merge submodules, I hope it helps you: https://lucasoshiro.github.io/posts-en/2022-03-12-merge-submodule/

I can't exactly figure out what happened with you submodules, but, if you merged **master** into **feature1** locally and it replaced 6c084 by 7b3325, one of the following happened:

- 7b3325 is a descendant commit of 6c084
- there was a conflict between **master** and **feature1** on **feature_submodule** (the commit that the submodule points to was diverging)

If you keep both the changes introduced by you and the other dev on **feature_submodule**, then you can do this (adapt it to the contribution workflow of the submodule):

1. enter the submodule (cd feature_submodule)
2. `git checkout` to 6c084
3. create a new branch point to it (`git checkout <new branch>`)
4. push the changes to the submodule remote repository (`git push <your remote> <new branch>`)
5. do whatever you do to have that branch merged onto the main branch (e.g. if you using GitHub, open a PR asking to merge the new branch onto the main branch of the submodule repository)
6. having the changes accepted and merged on the main branch of the submodule, run `git fetch` to download the newest commits and branches
7. `git checkout` your submodule to the main branch
8. now, back to the parent repo, assuming you are on **feature1** branch: `git add feature_submodule`, so now it will point to the newest changes, then `git commit`

Please note that I'm assuming that the commit that **feature_submodule** is pointing to on the **master** of the parent repository is already merged on the main branch of the submodule.